# What does a . in an import statement in Python mean?

Tags: python, module

I'm looking over the code for Python's `multiprocessing` module, and it contains this line:

```
from ._multiprocessing import win32, Connection, PipeConnection
```

instead of

```
from _multiprocessing import win32, Connection, PipeConnection
```

the subtle difference being the period before `_multiprocessing`. What does that mean? Why the period?

Comment: It's called relative import: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Without the `.`, if you had a file `_multiprocessing.py` for some indecipherable reason next to your main script, `multiprocessing` would break. With the `.`, it ensures it gets its own module.

Comment: If a `.` refers to peer modules, why would the documentation say to use a `.` when that multiprocessing module should be part of the regular sys.path libraries?  Does the question and Chris' clarification mix them up or am I not understanding?  Appreciate the help.

Comment: Another Question (now closed) with alternative, good answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511792/python-from-dotpackage-import-syntax

Answer (score 168, accepted):

That's the syntax for explicit [relative imports](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/). It means import from the current package.

Comment: What defines what the "current package" is?

Comment: It should say *from where the importing package is*. It basically means the current namespace or package directory.

Comment: Thanks, I think I know what you mean. Just to be clear, would you mind providing an example?

Comment: You can do things like:
`from . import peermodule`
`from .. import parentpackagemodule`

Comment: Can you use three dots to represent a grandparentpackagemodule? from ... import grandparentmodule

Comment: Here's where the real crux and explanation of _relative imports_ begins to get explained in the link you provided: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision.

Comment: Here's another good explanation from another (now closed) question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22511861/4561887.

Answer (score 38):

default one dot in your current folder, when you want to go parent folder you can do like this, my python version 3.6.3

[image]

Comment: You made the explanation so clear, instead of 1000 words. Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

The dot in the module name is used for relative module import (see [here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/import.html#tok-relative_module) and [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html),  section 6.4.2).

You can use more than one dot, referring not to the curent package but its parent(s). This should only be used within packages, in the main module one should always use absolute module names.