# Python "from [dot]package import ..." syntax

Tags: python, import

Looking through a Django tutorial I saw the following syntax:

```
from .models import Recipe, Ingredient, Instruction
```

Can someone explain how the .models works / what it does exactly? Usually I have:

```
from myapp.models import
```

How does it work without the myapp part in front of .models?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

The `.` is a shortcut that tells it to search in the *current* package before the rest of the `PYTHONPATH`. So, if a same-named module `Recipe` exists somewhere else in your `PYTHONPATH`, it won't be loaded.

Comment: @Hack-R - 2 dots represent parent directory.

Comment: @Bhindi oh thank you! I can't believe I didn't realize that

Comment: python checks for current directory first,so what is the use of . ?

Comment: @shadow0359 the "current" directory is not always the directory in which the script resides. The script could be imported into another script in a different directory.

Comment: These are called _relative imports_. See the full and official explanation here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision, and the other answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7279834/4561887.

Answer (score 1):

In addition of Sudeep Juvekar, this question is also related to `manage.py`'s behavior.

In [django-admin.py and manage.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/):

> It puts your project’s package on `sys.path`.