# Django error in urlpatterns: No module named views

Tags: python, django, django-1.7, django-1.8

In Django 1.7.x this construct was working:

```
# urls.py

import views

urlpatterns = ('',
   url(r'^$', views.index)
)
```

In Django 1.8.X it stopped working. Now I get this error message when I run the default Django server:

> No module named 'views'

I also tried this:

```
from system.views import *

urlpatterns = ('',
   url(r'^$', views.index)
)
```

This results in:

> name 'views' is not defined

And this:

```
from system import views

urlpatterns = ('',
   url(r'^$', views.index)
)
```

I also tried many more combinations that I've seen at stackoverflow, but none of them works. Hope someone can share what magic combination should do the trick.

**EDIT**

```
\home
  \jacobian
     \apps
        \apps
          __init__.py
          settings.py
          urls.py
          views.py
          ...
       \system
          __init__.py
          urls.py
          views.py
          ...
```

Comment: you should do `from apps.your_app_name import views`

Comment: I guess maybe you haven't registered the application in setting.py.

Comment: 1. I have registered application in INSTALLED_APPS 2. If I do `from proj.system import views`, then I get `no module named 'proj.system'`

Comment: you must show us your application's directory structure/tree for better help.

Comment: @Says. It worked literally for months, until I switched today to Django 1.8.x

Comment: @Jacobian why do you have two `apps` dir?

Comment: @ozgur when i did `$ django-admin startproject apps`, it created such a tree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried to recreate this issue. It seems that you are correct and just `import views` no longer works. However, the following import statement works fine for me:

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', views.index)
]
```

You can see an example here on the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#example). I also think this related Stack Overflow question can clarify they reason for dot import syntax:

Q: [Python "from [dot]package import ..." syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511792/python-from-dotpackage-import-syntax)

Answer (score 1):

You should include the views.py file from the application that you have created. So try

```
from <your app name>.views import *
```

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is a bit of a mix.

Before version 1.8 it was

```
from myapp import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('^$', views.myview),
    url('^other/$', views.otherview),
)
```

Now, from version 1.8, there is no need for the first void argument to `patterns` when assigning `urlpatterns`. Actually there is no need to call `patterns` at all.

Here is one example form my latest project with Django 1.8:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', HomePage.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'^play/', include('play.urls', namespace='play', app_name='play')),
]
```

And as described in the [Django 1.8 release docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#django-conf-urls-patterns):

> Thus patterns() serves little purpose and is a burden when teaching
>   new users (answering the newbie’s question “why do I need this empty
>   string as the first argument to patterns()?”). For these reasons, we
>   are deprecating it. Updating your code is as simple as ensuring that
>   urlpatterns is a list of django.conf.urls.url() instances.
>   For example:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from myapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    url('^$', views.myview),
    url('^other/$', views.otherview),
]
```

Comment: That is useful! Thank you, Pynchia.