# why it shows error that from . views can't be imported

Tags: django

**music/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

    url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9)+$', views.detail, name='detail'),

]
```

**followed by views.py code**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>this is something</h1>")

def detail(request, album_id):
    return HttpResponse("<h2> details of album " + str(album_id)+"</h2>")
```

the main url website is built correctly..

Comment: Is that question related to your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511792

Comment: Is the `views.py` file inside music directory?