# Importing in Python what does the . mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I am trying to follow some code in python 3.5 and I am still super newb level.

I have the following imports but I'm not sure what the differences are with the ones that begin with '.'?

```
import os
import time
import random
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import tensorflow as tf

from .base import BaseModel
from .history import History
from .replay_memory import ReplayMemory
from .ops import linear, conv2d, clipped_error
from utils import get_time, save_pkl, load_pkl
```

For example .base .history .replay_memory .ops

Where is it getting those modules? Are they getting them as a subset of one of the earlier modules?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279810/what-does-a-in-an-import-statement-in-python-mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a so called relative import see [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) and refers to modules or packages located in the same directory.
(More precisely, in the same package, which in most but [not all](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) cases will be the same thing.)