# Importing Python files in Aws Lambda causes error

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I'm currently in a school course where we have to do a software project for some client. Our project is a helper bot powered by Amazon Lex service and Amazon's Lambda function. Our issue is that for some reason the Lambda function does not have same kind of syntax for importing files that other Python 3.6 programs have. This causes problems because TravisCI won't build properly due to the different syntax and errors caused by it.

In the Lambda function the import needs to looks like this:

```
from custom_python_file import CustomClass
```

But in TravisCI, and I believe every in also everyother other platform it needs to be typed like this:

```
from .custom_python_file import CustomClass
```

We tried to do some workarounds, but none did work.

Any help?

Comment: Is Amazon Lambda using python 3 or python 2? It seems to me that it is using python 2

Comment: Lambda supports both Python 2 and 3, but we are using 3, 3.6 to be exact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python `.` is used for **relative imports**. It simply means that it is importing from the same package.

Refer [this tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279810/what-does-a-in-an-import-statement-in-python-mean) for the same.

Comment: Why would this fail on Travis then? Also pycharm is continuosly compiling, and it gives error when I have import typed in without a dot

Comment: @LasseLiimatta after little research i got to know new things and i have updated my answer.

Comment: I think this is most likely what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how is this answers OP's question.