# Proper relative imports: "Unable to import module"

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I have a project structured like this:

```
.
└── myapp
    ├── app.py
    ├── models
    │   ├── hello.py
    │   └── world.py
    └── requirements.txt
```

I have two models, `hello` and `world`. Both models are used from `app.py` where I import them like this:

```
from models.hello import Hello
from models.world import World
```

But `world` also needs to use `hello`. I tried this in `world.py`:

```
from models.hello import Hello
```

The above technically works when I run the app, but VSCode's Python extension gives me the following error:

```
E0401:Unable to import 'models.hello'.
```

What is the proper way of importing a submodule from the same directory? How do I avoid this error in VSCode?

Comment: Hope you have __init__ file in all your modules.

Answer (score 36):

The error you are receiving is one that's reported by a python linter named `pylint`. So the problem isn't really specific to the vscode extension.

There are two solutions:

1. Please try adding an `.env` file in your project directory with the vape `PYTHONPATH=./myapp`, this will tell pylint where to find your modules
2. Or just open the folder `myapp` in vscode directly instead of opening the parent directory in vscode.

Comment: Using the `.env` file solves the problem I had with VS Code being unable to ctrl+click navigate to imported local classes. Thanks!

Comment: I seem to be too stupid for this. Could you please more specific and give an example with a reference to a venv? I don't get the myapp definition as well. Thanks

Comment: @Christian you create a `.env` file at the root of your project and inside of it put the variable `PYTHONPATH=path_to_your_package`. In the author example the path to is package from the root is `./myapp` so he needed to put in the env file the variable `PYTHONPATH=./myapp`

Answer (score 8):

The error is coming from pylint. You need to add this line into settings.json file (VS Code):

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--init-hook",
        "import sys; sys.path.append('<absolute path to myapp directory>')"],
```

Comment: I have a venv for every project. Which abolute path is ment?

Comment: I do not use venv. But as per the doco, you can try to play with these parameters: sys.prefix and sys.exec_prefix. https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: Another option just to switch to a different linter. Recently I started to use flake8 and so far no trouble at all.

Comment: I've been searching for hours and this fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: What is wrong with using from models.hello import Hello? Is there any explanation of the error or is it that the vs extension is not able to understand imports correctly?

Comment: It is an extension issue. Try to use any other linter for the same code. A real issue has to be highlighted by any linter.

Answer (score 5):

In your your `.vscode/settings.json` (in the root directory of your workspace) you need these two lines:

one to use the pylint in your virtual environment (if you have one) so that pylint is aware of it. You'll want to adjust the below if your pylint or virtual environment is located in a different place.

```json
  "python.linting.pylintPath": "${workspaceFolder}/api/venv/bin/pylint"
```

and one, as Shtefan [mentions above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55429151/11312371), to let pylint know where the python part of your project is:

```json
  "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--init-hook",
    "import sys; sys.path.append('${workspaceFolder}/api')"
  ]
```

---

This additional line may be helpful if you don't already have vscode setup with your virtual environment, once again you may have to modify if your virtual environment path does not match the below.

```json
  "python.pythonPath": "${workspaceFolder}/api/venv/bin/python",
```

Answer (score 4):

Since **hello.py** and **world.py** are in the same folder (aka package), you should import the Hello class in **world.py** as follow:

```
from .hello import Hello
```

As described in this thread: [What does a . in an import statement in Python mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279810/what-does-a-in-an-import-statement-in-python-mean)

The `.` is here to indicate the import from the current package.

Comment: This solves the vscode error buy breaks the application. `app.py` is the entry point for the application, so even in **world.py** I can't import from **hello** because **hello** is in **models** and not the project root directory. I get `no module named 'hello'`

Comment: @JimmySanchez you're correct, I have updated my answer. It should be `from .hello import Hello`

Comment: What is wrong with using `from models.hello import Hello`? Is there any explanation of the error or is it that the vs extension is not able to understand imports correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `__init__.py` file in the directory `models/`. At the very least, you need an empty file called `models/__init__.py`. With this, so long as you run `python` from the `myapp/` directory, you will be able to do `from models.hello import Hello`.