# Difference between import file and import .file

Tags: python, import

Quick question, what is the difference between

```
import file
import .file
```

Can someone explain the difference between them? Can someone explain all kinds of importing to me?

Comment: `import .file` is a syntax error.

Comment: [This](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) will explain all kinds of importing to you. Do you have specific questions?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf: No, `import .file` is a syntax error, and even with the corrected syntax, your description is wrong. Relative imports are about packages, not directories.

Comment: @user2357112, you are right. I got confuse because `from .file import something` works.

Answer (score 0):

```
import .file
```

It's the new syntax for explicit relative imports. It means import from the current package. This is the current namespace or package directory.

You can use more than one dot, referring not to the current package but its parent(s). This should only be used within packages, in the main module.

Comment: No, it isn't as it used in the cases I mentioned above. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279810/what-does-a-in-an-import-statement-in-python-mean

Comment: If you look closely, you'll find that not a single post on that page tries to use `import .file` syntax. It's all `from` imports.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to use functions of other modules.

First is importing the whole Module.

```
import math      #this will import math module
print(math.sqrt(4))  #Using function of math module
```

Second Method is by importing the function not module

```
from math import sqrt     #this will import sqrt function not full module
print(sqrt(4))     #Using function of math module
```

Note some more suggestions
1. you can also import module and function by using **as** and import it under n alias name,
Example 
import math as ilovemaths  #importing under alias name
print(ilovemaths.sqrt(4))    #using the function of module.

2. You can also * to import functions but then the problem will be of conflicting names. So be specific and choose the best method to import.