# Various path styles

Tags: python-3.x

What is the difference between doing:

```
from utils import *
```

And:

```
from .utils import *
```

Are these one and the same thing, or do they actually address something different? When should one be used over the other?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does a . in an import statement in Python mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279810/what-does-a-in-an-import-statement-in-python-mean)

Comment: @wjandrea sort of...looking at the docs [here](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) makes it even more confusing for me.

Comment: The docs here might be clearer (haven't read them myself): [Packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) > [Intra-package References](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references)